# How to add an icon to your custom folder using material-icon-theme?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm trying to personalize a custom folder named navigator, and I would like to use the theme used for the routing folder but I don't want to name it as 'router'

Here is my settings.json
[image: settings.json]

I tried to set it using the name as it is shown in the [documentation](https://material-theme.com/docs/reference/folder-associations/#routes)

[image]

and also as in the [code](https://github.com/PKief/vscode-material-icon-theme/blob/d7c0fa80ac9b29f8c52d44ddc122d109db459611/src/icons/folderIcons.ts#L297) but it didn't work as expected.

[image]

Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that using the word **"routes"** has fixed the issue.

I believed that the name you should write should be like in the 'name', but apparently only with **routes** worked.

[image: image with the routing icon in a custom folder]

If someone can give an explanation would be appreciated for if in the future someone else wants to change the icons for their custom folders.